# Callback for 'From' field drop down in outlook

Tags: visual-c++, outlook, outlook-addin, mapi

While composing a mail, on clicking 'From' an option to send from other email address can be seen. Is there a MAPI callback which helps to populate the email addresses when 'From' drop down is clicked?
Which is the MAPI callback called when 'From' field is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no callbacks. Outlook builds that list from the list of accounts, it then adds the one-off entries (marked with X) that the user explicitly added. That list is stored in the profile section.

Comment: Is there a way to add new entries programatically ( like the user added )? Are the entries added by the user stored in the profile section ?

Comment: Yes - you need to open the corresponding profile section - read PROP_ACCT_PREFERENCES_UID property from the corresponding IOlkAccount object, use that uid to cal lMAPISession::OpenProfileSecrtion. 0x0483101F will contain the list of addresses. Take a look at the data in OutlookSpy (clic kIOLkAccountMAnager).

Comment: i am able to access the list of addresses from 0x0483101F property. How do i add a new one? How do i allocate memory? I can see the newly added ones in the outlook spy but not in the from drop down. Also when i add a new one manually, programatically added ones are gone. I see maximum of 9 can be added. Is that so? Also newly added goes to the index 9 and then index 8 and so on. Am i right?

Comment: can we add the entries to 0x0483101F property programatically? @Dmitry

Comment: For the drop down to list the entries added programatically, 0x0484 needs to be updated with the last index updated and Outlook needs to restarted.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me when the values were updated on Outlook startup.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is 0x0484 is for? What should be its value?
 @Dmitry

Comment: Set that property to 0 to tell Outlook to use all the addresses (AFAIK it is the starting index of the first good entry).